# How to lateral flatten a varchar column which is not in an array format in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to  lateral flatten a varchar to an array to explode the element within the array

For example [trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4WeraV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM]

I tried the following:

1. I tried to replace the varchar space  with `,"` (doesn't work).
2. Used `strtok_to_array` --> gets unicode start of string

```sql
 Select s.value, replace(varchar_col,' ',',"') as to_array_format,
strtok_to_array(varchar_col,'')as strtok_to_array,* from table , lateral flatten(input => strtok_to_array(varchar_col,''))s
```

Actual result:

```
1. trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4WeraV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM
2. [ "trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4Wer\u0002aV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD\u0002bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM" ]
```

Expected Result:

```
1. ["trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4Wer","aV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD","bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM"]
2. ["trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4Wer","aV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD","bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM"]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the output you're getting, it looks like your data contains null bytes. If you want to split the string into an array using the null bytes as the boundary, you can use

`strtok_to_array(varchar_col,hex_decode_string('00'))`

[hex_decode_string](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/hex_decode_string.html) takes a hex-encoded string as input, and passing '00' returns a null byte, which we then use as the separator.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that still dint resolve the issue it still gets me [ "trJGrODW4n4iLRN2A4Wer\u0002aV740vH4L81ikd7KnRfsD\u0002bE578vR4L81isq7YnRchM" ]

Comment: the `\u0002` is telling you the "value" you "don't want" is 0002 which suggests to me `strtok_to_array(varchar_col,hex_decode_string('02'))` should cover you use case.